# How to compare values within registers in MIPS?

Tags: if-statement, assembly, mips

I am trying to create a function that prompts the user to enter a number between 3 and 30 and if the number is less than 3 it will display "your number is less than 3", and if the number is greater than 30 it will display "your number is greater than 30". This may be dumb but I am new to MIPS and I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter your number (3-30):"
message: .asciiz "\n Your number is "
message2: .asciiz "\n Your number is less than 3"
message3: .asciiz "\n Your number is more than 30"
.text 
# Prompt the user to enter the number
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

# Get the number 
li $v0, 5 #get an integer from the user
syscall

# Store the result in t0
move $t0, $v0

main: #syscall to end the program
    addi $t1, $zero, 0
    addi $t2, $zero, 3
    addi $t3, $zero, 30

    ble $t0, $t1, numberSmaller
    bge $t0, $t2, numberLarger

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

numberSmaller:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message2
    syscall
numberLarger:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message3
    syscall
```

Comment: I don't know MIPS either but `ble $t0, $t1, numberSmaller
    bge $t0, $t2, numberLarger

    li $v0, 10` : the third line is not reachable since there are opposite conditions branching somewhere else just above. and `bge` and `ble` wil also branch on equality. You probably need `bgt` and `blt`

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is (e.g.. how do your current results differ from the expected result?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually pretty close.

The `main:` label is in the wrong place, so under some simulators, the first few instructions may not be executed.

Also, the program is [somewhat] incomplete because after the conditional branch is taken, the program "falls off the end of the world".

But, the core of the problem is the two branches need different branch conditions and the second register in each needs to be changed:

Change:

```
ble $t0, $t1, numberSmaller
```

Into:

```
blt $t0, $t2, numberSmaller
```

Change:

```
bge $t0, $t2, numberLarger
```

Into:

```
bgt $t0, $t3, numberLarger
```

---

So, here's the fully corrected program:

```
    .data
prompt:     .asciiz     "Enter your number (3-30):"
message:    .asciiz     "\n Your number is "
message2:   .asciiz     "\n Your number is less than 3"
message3:   .asciiz     "\n Your number is more than 30"

    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    # Prompt the user to enter the number
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,prompt
    syscall

    # Get the number
    li      $v0,5                   # get an integer from the user
    syscall

    # Store the result in t0
    move    $t0,$v0

    addi    $t1,$zero,0
    addi    $t2,$zero,3
    addi    $t3,$zero,30

    blt     $t0,$t2,numberSmaller
    bgt     $t0,$t3,numberLarger

    # output message to show the number
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,message
    syscall

    # show the number
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$t0
    syscall

exit:
    li      $v0,10                  # syscall to end the program
    syscall

numberSmaller:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,message2
    syscall
    j       exit

numberLarger:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,message3
    syscall
    j       exit
```

---

Here's a slightly tighter version:

```
    .data
prompt:     .asciiz     "Enter your number (3-30):"
message:    .asciiz     "\n Your number is "
message2:   .asciiz     "\n Your number is less than 3"
message3:   .asciiz     "\n Your number is more than 30"

    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    # Prompt the user to enter the number
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,prompt
    syscall

    # Get the number
    li      $v0,5                   # get an integer from the user
    syscall

    # Store the result in t0
    move    $t0,$v0

    li      $t1,3
    blt     $t0,$t1,numberSmaller

    li      $t1,30
    bgt     $t0,$t1,numberLarger

    # output message to show the number
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,message
    syscall

    # show the number
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$t0
    syscall

exit:
    li      $v0,10                  # syscall to end the program
    syscall

numberSmaller:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,message2
    syscall
    j       exit

numberLarger:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,message3
    syscall
    j       exit
```